# Simplify algebraic equation with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Am solving an 8th grade math text book, and I came across this one:

If $(xy)^{a - 1} = z$, $(yz)^{b - 1} = x$, $(xz)^{c - 1} = y$, and $xyz \ne -1, 0, 1$, then what is $ab + bc + ca$?

Please help.

Comment: If $x=y=z$, then we get that $ a = b = c = \frac{3}{2}$ and so $ab+bc+ca = \frac{27}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Notice that $(xy)^a = (yz)^b = (zx)^c = xyz$

*Expanded based on OP's comment*

The above equation defines $a$, $b$ and $c$ in terms of $x$,$y$,$z$, so the final answer depends on $x$, $y$ and $z$.

We can solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$ as
$$
a = \frac{\log x + \log y + \log z}{\log x + \log y}, 
b = \frac{\log x + \log y + \log z}{\log y + \log z}, 
c = \frac{\log x + \log y + \log z}{\log x + \log y} 
$$
It is easy to calculate
$$
\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} = \frac{ab + bc + ca}{abc}$$
and get the answer:
$${{2\,\left(\log z+\log y+\log x\right)^3}\over{\left(\log y+\log x
 \right)\,\left(\log z+\log x\right)\,\left(\log z+\log y\right)}}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the hint? How does that allow you to calculate $ab+bc+ca$?

Answer (score 1):

As $(xy)^a = (yz)^b = (zx)^c = xyz$ we have $(xy)^{abc}=(xyz)^{bc}$,
$(yz)^{abc}=(xyz)^{ac}$, and $(zx)^{abc}=(xyz)^{ab}$. Multiplying these three equations: $(x^2y^2z^2)^{abc}=(xyz)^{ab+bc+ac}$ we conclude that
$$2abc=ab+ac+bc.$$